# Basis of a basis-linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Usually when we say that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are basis we imply that they are linearly independent and span the space. We by default denote $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $i$-$j$ basis. Then how is $i$-$j$ basis defined in the first place?

Comment: Wrong place to ask such a question. You should head to Mathematics.SE.

Comment: The notation $i,j$ is use, I think, on a $2$-dimensional space that already has two preferential directions that are linearly independent. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the space of pairs of real numbers, considered as a vector space with real coefficients, there are two directions, those of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, that people often take a preferential. It is, of course, a choice. In an abstract vector space, there may not be a reason any pair of directions is preferential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not by default use any $i-j$ basis, no matter what that actually means. A vector space is a set of things called vectors together with an algebraic structure satisfying the axioms of a vector space. Vectors can be anything in the world, including tuples like $(x,y)$, functions, matrices, or a bunch of elephants. In any such vector space, a basis is any set of linearly independent vectors that also span the entire space. Just like a vector has no $i-j$ form, nor does a basis have such a form. In some vector spaces vectors are either directly given as tuples (e.g., $\mathbb R^3$), or can be uniquely represented as tuples once a basis is chosen. If your question is how to find the coordinates vector of a given vector in a given basis, the answer is that it is pretty much immediate from the definition of a basis; spanning means coordinates exist, and linear independence means the coordinates are unique.